# Autoloading Sparks using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to autoload sparks via CI's `$autoload['sparks']` index.

Apparently it doesn't autoload.

I've tried to run it using `$this->load->spark('spark_name/version');`, it works.

Comment: Well that's good news. Thanks for letting us know.

Answer (score 1):

Because the syntax is wrong, if it's a model it should be :

```
$autoload['model'] = array('spark_name/version');
```

if library :

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('spark_name/version');
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

Indeed making `$autoload['sparks']=array('sparkname/version');` works. Check if you have multiple autoload.php files.